# How do you automatically run a .bat file from a flashdrive with cmd programming?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a way to run a .bat file named File.bat from a flash drive, as soon as the flash drive is inserted into the computer. I am currently running Windows 10, and I am using notepad++ in conjunction with cmd. Since the `Autorun.inf` functionality was discontinued in windows 7 for security reasons, that is not an option. I could also use a U3 flash drive, but I'm looking for something that I can just code in or experiment with, rather than purchase for especially. I am not an expert with cmd and I am unaware of many of its functions, but I do know enough to be considered a beginner, if not novice. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If there were any way to autorun something in a flash drive it would already have been discovered by hackers, exploited and patched long ago... just like autorun.inf. There'll need to be some kind of interaction from the user.

Comment: You can for example boot from a bootable USB, but that requires BIOS changes, a Linux install etc.

Comment: In this case, I'm using someone else computer, whereas they most likely will not have these specifications. However, thank you for responding, as this is my first question. So, let me describe my situation. I have a 4GB sandisk flash drive, and I would like to run the file listed, as soon as it is plugged in, so no user interface or setup is required.

Comment: Now that that option is out of the way, how would I go about using a U3 flash drive with a second cd partition to exploit the autorun.inf functionality?

Comment: I have read many articles about them, but they were too vague or were wrote for a programmer of higher caliber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a autorun.inf

write this inside

```
[autorun]
open=a. bat
```

Comment: I will have to test this when my shipment of U3 flash drives come in, but thanks for the code.

Comment: Sorry for useless answer

Comment: No, its not useless, I just need to wait a few days before testing, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set evtDevice = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent")

Wscript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = evtDevice.NextEvent
    'report an event
    Wscript.Echo " Win32_Device Changed event occurred" & VBNewLine
    If objReceivedEvent.EventType = 1 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Config Changed" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 2 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Arrived" 

         Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Volume")
         For Each objItem in colItems
               Wscript.Echo objitem.DriveType
               If objitem.DriveType = 2 then
                        Wscript.Echo objItem.DriveType & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.driveletter
                End If
        Next
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 3 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Left" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Computer Docked" 
    End If
Loop
```

This waits for the volumes to change.

Comment: And just for the sake of absolute clarity, I would just need to paste this to *what* type of file within my flash drive?

Comment: *also*, Is this ready to copy and paste, or do I have to insert my specifications into the file?

Comment: It has to be running on the receiving computer. It's triggered by the type of volumes changing on the computer. It is littered with message boxes. It is VBScript, so a .vbs file.

Comment: To put this into perspective, lets say when I plug in this flash, it is the first time I have interacted with the target computer, in this case, I wouldn't be able to run that script, I would need it to run from my flash drive, but this still was a huge contribution, thanks.